# Run TensorFlow 2.0 on CPU without AVX

Tags: python, tensorflow, windows-10

I would like to install and use TensorFlow 2.0. I have a PC with Windows 10, a Geforce GTX 1080 Ti GPU and an old [Intel Xeon X5660 CPU](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/de/de/ark/products/47921/intel-xeon-processor-x5660-12m-cache-2-80-ghz-6-40-gt-s-intel-qpi.html), which doesn't support AVX.

Now, my problem is that there is a DLL Import error whenever I attempt to run any TensorFlow code on this machine. I know about [this repository](https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel) providing a solution for legacy CPUs but unfortunately I can't find any TensorFlow 2.0 packages there.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a brand new wheel file in the repository:

https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel

The following file is working very well:

https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel/blob/master/2.0.0/py37/GPU/cuda101cudnn76sse2/tensorflow_gpu-2.0.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

As stated in the Readme.md:

"It will take time for compiling when execute TensorFlow first time."

Take a look at this test:

```
>>>import tensorflow as tf
tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll

>>>print(tf.__version__)
2.0.0

>>>from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
>>>print(device_lib.list_local_devices())

tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1050 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.531
GPU libraries are statically linked, skip dlopen check.
Adding visible gpu devices: 0
Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
     0
0:   N
Created TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0 with 1340 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1050, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)

[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 4456898788177247918
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 1406107238
locality {
  bus_id: 1
  links {
  }
}
incarnation: 3224787151756357043
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1050, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1"
]
```

Comment: I tried the whl linked in the answer but encountered an error of cublas64_10.dll not found, even though I have the dll in the bin folder. So I tried another source and this worked for me. https://github.com/jurneo/tf_wheel_2.0_gpu_woavx_win10/releases/tag/v2.0.0

Answer (score 2):

you can download and install NO AVX whl from source:
https://github.com/yaroslavvb/tensorflow-community-wheels/issues/174

Answer (score 1):

I had that same issue with tensorflow running on i5 650, which doesn't support avx.

But I fixed that issue by simply uninstalling the original installation, and installing this unofficial build from this link:
https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel/blob/master/2.0.0/py37/CPU/sse2/tensorflow-2.0.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

Just install this .whl file using pip and then try to run your script.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, so I compiled TF 2.4 without AVX support for Python3.  [Wheel is here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rnmn205f1skj139/tensorflow-2.3.0-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl?dl=0).

My [write-up on it is here](https://www.eggwall.com/2020/09/compiling-tensorflow-without-avx.html). If anyone needs an updated version for TF or Python, find my email address and I can compile a new wheel.

Comment: Vikram, nice job! Just edit that it must be Python3.8 (3.10 not working). I'm not sure if this is trivial, but wasn't for me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install TensorFlow using Anaconda that sometimes has build able to install TensorFlow on older CPUs which has no support for AVX (Advanced Vector Extensions).

```
> conda create -n tf_env tensorflow=2
```