# Import and Run Tensorflow 2 on linux machine that does not support AVX instructions

Tags: redhat, avx, tensorflow2.x

I am on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 and have installed TensorFlow 2.1.0 on this machine.

Whenever I try to import TensorFlow as follows:

```
import tensorFlow as tf
```

It gives the following error:

```
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

I have done some research and figured that it happens because my machine does not support AVX.

I found a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58198180/run-tensorflow-2-0-on-cpu-without-avx) that solves similar issue on a windows machine. I was wondering if there is any way to solve it on a Linux machine?

I used more /proc/cpuinfo | grep flags to get the flags supported by my CPU. Followings are the flags supported on my machine:

```
fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl aperfmperf eagerfpu pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm dca sse4_1 lahf_lm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority dtherm
```

I know that the problem will be gone if I use tensorflow version 1.5, but at this point I am cannot downgrade it to 1.5.

Is there any way to import and run tensorflow 2.1.0 on a machine that does not support AVX instructions?