# Dll load failed

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, importerror, tensorflow-datasets, python-3.8

My code is this, this is a test code from a youtuber:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
import mathplotlib.pyplot as plt
(training_images, training_labels), (testing_images,
                                     testing_labels) = datasets.cifar10.load_data()
training_images, testing_images = training_images/255, training_labels/255
class_names = ['Plane', 'Car']

for i in range(16):
    plt.subplot(4, 4, i+1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.imshow(training_images[i], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    plt.xlabel(class_names[training_labels[i][0]])
plt.show()
```

And this is what happens when I run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "image classification test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I installed tensorflow from both anaconda and pip and same error happens, I cant seem to find a solution on this one so please help me out

Answer (score 0):

The optimistic quick check, make sure you have the latest [Visual C++ DLL installed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0).

I just encountered this myself; in my case the system I was trying to run Tensorflow on uses a G3220.  According to [Issue #39007](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39007#issuecomment-621004773) TensorFlow requires AVX extensions, which my CPU does not support.  You can do a quick check to see if your processor supports AVX extensions by searching for it on the [Intel Ark](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark.html#@Processors) (Link to my [G3220](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/77773/intel-pentium-processor-g3220-3m-cache-3-00-ghz.html) which does not support AVX and a link to a [i7-4790](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/80806/intel-core-i7-4790-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-00-ghz.html) that does support AVX.  I suspect this is the same problem that you are having.

You may be able to compile TF yourself or use a build someone else made to run without AVX (see: [Run TensorFlow 2.0 on CPU without AVX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58198180/run-tensorflow-2-0-on-cpu-without-avx#58443987)).  In my case, I was able to use the unofficial TF python build referenced in this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58443987/7748511) to install TF 2.4 from here https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel.

[Intel Ark i7-4790 AVX Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWFzB.png)